# Azure Logic Apps - Logging for Business Audit

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics

I have built an integration solution between 2 systems.

Azure  Logic App provides logged capability but it is mainly meant for Azure developers.

I have a requirment to maintain logging of my logic app based on some predefined events as mentioned below :-

1. Pick up newly added files from FTP folder
2. Unzip
3. Process the files and merge
4. Send merge files to Azure functions
   .
   .
   .

Requirement of this logging is for auditors who are non technical people.

We have Azure SQL database in which I can create customised logging tables as we used to do in traditional applications. For this I am thinking of creating a Web UI for auditors to see the logs details.

I just wanted to check

I just wanted to check, is there any other way to achieve the same by leveraging Azure logs and showing them in WebUI.

Looking for better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I didn't get any response. However, I would like to share how and what I have implemented this :-

1) Define stages for the entire process -   It defines stages in the Life Cycle of your process. (I have defined Stages as per the actions/steps in my Logic App work flow) 
2) After finalizing all the stages, create a master table in Azure database to stages where I also need to store the audit log for each process in AuditLog table.
3) Now in my Logic App, I have using a variable, which maintains StageId,DateTimeStamp for all stages.   eg: Stage1Id,DateTime1;Stage2Id,DateTime2;Stage3Id,DateTime3;
4) In the end of Logic App is making a call to AuditLogStoredProcedure with this variable as parameter to insert values in the  AuditLog table.

```
***Please note that: -
1)  I have declared one stage as an "Error" which being called up in a similar way for all exceptions.
2)  I am maintaining StagesId with TimeStamps in a variable to avoid multiple calls to the database. For audit log there will be only single call to database from the LogicApp.
***
```

[image]